# Is there a database of math conversations with Chat GPT?

Tags: math, problem-solving

I would like to make GPT (or other AI Chat, if someone knows better) to assist me in my mathematical education. But hard to say what GPT is capable to do. Some testing tasks are performed well by him, others worse. Maybe there is a database of such conversations when I could learn what is possible with Chat GPT, even if they are leading evidently to bad solutions? Please let me know.  If not how to test his capabilities to know what is possible for him, and when for sure he will be making errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bot I'm asking about repository for different math conversations ( to learn from them) about mathematicial characteristics of Chat) Additionally I would like to know methods (fast methods) how to test Chat GPT to define what is possible for him in mathematics  and what is not  at the current moment.